# F# REPL for VS (2012)?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2012, read-eval-print-loop

Hi is there a simple F# REPL for VS 2012, so I don't have to create a project, for simple calculations I can make on the fly?

I feel like having a tab or toolbox for it docked as one as the following tabs:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this via the [F# Interactive window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx) in Visual Studio.

This is available from `View`->`Other Windows`->`F# Interactive`, or `Ctrl+Alt+F` if you have the default Visual Studio key bindings setup.

Comment: @Shimmy It shoudl open up started - try typing `#help;;` within the window, then hit `Enter`

Answer (score 4):

View -> Other Windows -> F# Interactive